# NextJs firebase hosting build on github actions not reading environment variables

Tags: firebase, github, next.js, github-actions, firebase-hosting

I am deploying a NextJs application on Firebase hosting using Github Actions.

I have the following workflow file:

```
name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  build-and-deploy-hosting:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: hosting
    steps:
      - name: Check out latest version of the code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install Node.js and NPM
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: "14"
      - name: Make envfile
        uses: SpicyPizza/create-envfile@v1
        with:
          envkey_NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY: '${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY }}'
          envkey_NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID: '${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID }}'
          envkey_NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN: '${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN }}'
          envkey_NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET: '${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET }}'
          envkey_NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID: '${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID }}'
          envkey_NEXT_PUBLIC_DEVELOPMENT: false
          file_name: .env.local
          directory: ./
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run build
      - run: npm run export
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNTxxx }}'
          channelId: live
          projectId: xxxx
        env:
          FIREBASE_CLI_PREVIEWS: hostingchannels
```

Typically, NextJs looks for an .env.local file with the environment variables placed within it. So I added these as secrets in the Github repo and then reference them in the build file by making an .env.local file.

But it's never recognized because when the Action runs, I get the following error:

```
> Build error occurred
[Error: Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly.] ***
  type: 't',
  code: 'auth/invalid-api-key',
  a: null
***
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! xxx@0.1.0 build: `next build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
```

Answer (score 3):

I used the ENV context referenced in the [GitHub docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets#using-encrypted-secrets-in-a-workflow), which seems more straightforward.

This [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66247264/github-actions-how-can-i-make-my-env-variablestored-in-env-file-available-i) solved my final issue, the ENV context needs to be added at the top level above jobs.

for example:

```
name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge
'on':
  push:
    branches:
      - main
env:
  NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PUBLIC_API_KEY: ${{secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PUBLIC_API_KEY}}

jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this is triggered by using quotes around the mustache templates (the `${{ secrets.SOME_NAME }}` bits) which causes them to be interpreted literally rather than get replaced.

```
name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  build-and-deploy-hosting:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: hosting
    steps:
      - name: Check out latest version of the code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install Node.js and NPM
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: "14"
      - name: Make envfile
        uses: SpicyPizza/create-envfile@v1
        with:
          envkey_NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY }}
          envkey_NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID }}
          envkey_NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN: ${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN }}
          envkey_NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET }}
          envkey_NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID: ${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID }}
          envkey_NEXT_PUBLIC_DEVELOPMENT: false
          file_name: .env.local
          directory: ./
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run build
      - run: npm run export
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          firebaseServiceAccount: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNTxxx }}
          channelId: live
          projectId: xxxx
        env:
          FIREBASE_CLI_PREVIEWS: hostingchannels
```